# data.table, dplyr etc. objects masking

Tags: r, methods, data.table, dplyr

Should I use `dtplyr` instead of `data.table` and `dplyr` ? should I be afraid of using `dplyr` or `data.table` (standalone) as they are masking so many function from 'default' packages such as `zoo`, `xts` etc. ? What is good practice here ? As both `dplyr` and `data.table` are on the `CRAN` I suppose, autors conducted some good practices, or maybe there are no guidelines to follow ? I see many silimar questions about objects masking, I wonder if `dplyr` objects naming isn't too messy or is it so straightforward that it was the best choice ?

```
> library(dplyr)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
data.table + dplyr code now lives in dtplyr.
Please library(dtplyr)!
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:data.table’:

    between, first, last

The following objects are masked from ‘package:xts’:

    first, last

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
```

Comment: You can run `conflicts(detail = TRUE)` if you want to know the conflicts. Other than that I'm not sure what is the quesiton is about. This is very opinion based. If you ask me, I would tell you not to use `dplyr` at all. If you ask 99.9% of the user on [r] on SO they will tell you they don't care about conflicts as long Hadley wrote it. Also, I can't find anything `data.table` is masking from base R. `zoo` and `xts` are not *default* functions and `data.table` just probably has methods for those for `data.tble` objects *only* (unlike dplyrs `setdiff` or `filter`, etc.).

Comment: Type `data.table::last` into the console, for example, and you'll see that it *does* explicitly handle its conflict with `xts::last`. My guess is that this applies to all data.table functions that conflict with popular packages.

Answer (score 4):

If the conflicts are a concern to you then try *not* loading dplyr and instead place dplyr:: in front of any dplyr function that you wish to use.  The `%>%` in dplyr comes from the magrittr package and it has no conflicts so you could still load that.  For example,

```
library(magrittr)

iris %>% dplyr::group_by(Species) %>% dplyr::summarize_all(mean)
```

or define the functions from dplyr you want to use like this:

```
library(magrittr)

group_by <- dplyr::group_by
summarize_all <- dplyr::summarize_all

iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarize_all(mean)
```